# VsCode TypeScript PathAuthoCompletion Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm learning Angular and VS Code works fine with that. Even when I'm using a class that is not imported, VS Code imports that for me automatically.
But there is a problem, when I want to import a file on myself (like `import * as file from '../filename'` or `import {} from '../file'`) VS Code doesn't suggest file and path names!

---

### What I tried so far:

1. Installing `Path Intellisense` and `Path Autocomplete` extensions.
2. Add and remove these entries in `tsconfig.json` file:

   - `"paths": { "app/*": ["./app/*"] }`
   - `"baseUrl": "./src"`
   - `"baseUrl": "./"`
   - `"include": [ "./src/app/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.ts" ]`.
3. Setting `typescript.suggest.paths` and `javascript.suggest.paths` on and off in vscode `settings.json` file.

None of above solutions worked! It seems to be problem with VS Code (it's in last update version for me) which i think can't find path and files and off course can't load them.
After struggling with that, I just need help from the community.

Any help will be pleasant!
**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Are you using VS Code or VS Code Insiders? Before your latest update it worked?

Comment: @Batajus As in the Help>About it's Visual studio code. and before updating that was not working.